# Copy and rename file

Tags: powershell

How to copy then rename the file? Example I have file CSC_KPI_2011201 and I want copy this file to other location follow by rename it to KPI_DATA_2011201. "2011201" is a variable string, i.e. it can be any value.

This is the code I would like to rewrite. `$file.FullName` contains the original file name and `$output_path` is the destination directory.

```
Copy-Item $file.FullName $output_path
```

Comment: Add new file name to `$output_path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide the full path (including the new name) as the destination:

```
$dst = Join-Path $output_path ($file.Name -replace 'CSC_KPI_','KPI_DATA_')
Copy-Item $file.FullName $dst
```

Comment: This will copy the original file and create new file call 'KPI_DATA_2011201' which does not meet my requriement

Comment: @user664481 Then you should've stated your requirements more clearly. See updated answer.